# Writing SQL queries in notebook in Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I am trying to write queries in notebooks in Azure synapse analytics. However, it really limits me. I cannot write the long queries. I think it cuts off when it sees that tab in the queries.

Anybody has any workaround this issue?

Comment: Hi @ms_2022, could you please provide additional information about the problem that you are facing when writing sql queries in synapse notebooks?

Comment: Thanks @RakeshGovindula-MT! I found a solution. Adding 3 quotes before  and after the query works

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, [@ms_2022](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19210574/ms-2022) for sharing your findings in the comment section. Posting the same on your behalf as an answer so that if anyone faces the same issue in future he would get the solution here.

**Long SQL queries in Synapse Notebook can be written by using 3 quotes at the starting and ending of the query.** This works fine.